# Ruby on Rails 3.2 Form Create Error using a dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am a Ruby on Rails newbie and having an issue using a dropdown on a Create form. This is the error I receive:

undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #8):

5:                          :message => "You must fix the following fields:",
6:                          :header_tag => :h3 %> -->
7:     
8:        <%= f.select :subCategoryId, options_for_select(@subcategories_for_select, {:prompt => 'Select a SubCategory...'}) %>
9:     
10:       <%=f.label :name%>
11:       <%=f.text_field :name%>

**Here is my new.html.erb:**

## New equipment

"Invalid Equipment!",
                         :message => "You must fix the following fields:",
                         :header_tag => :h3 %> -->
    
        'Select a SubCategory...'}) %>

If you were to submit the form without selecting a value from the drop-down, I would expect the validation errors to be shown.

Note: If I remove the drop-down, my Create form works fine.

I would appreciate anyone's help who can show me what I am doing incorrectly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I swapped out the variable @subcategories_for_select in the original select for the following:

```
<%= select("SubCategory", "name", options_for_select(SubCategory.all.map{ |p| [p.name, p.id, {:class => p.category_id}] }), {:prompt => 'Select a SubCategory...'}) %>
```

It all works now!